# Salesforce Account as Entry source in Journey Builder Does NOT work

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I use as an entry source Salesforce Data. In case i want to target leads, i choose Lead ID everything works properly. Now, i want a journey for Accounts that i have in Salescloud.I tried everything but nothing worked. 
[image: When i select Account]

I tried also selecting Contact by using Account ID ( PersonAccount)
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot target business accounts, so you can utilise the fact that every PersonAccount in Sales/Service Cloud has a Contact record associated with it. This Contact is linked via **"Person Contact ID (Contact)"**, which needs to be used in the "Who do you want to inject?" step.

If you like to trigger the Journey for Business accounts you can only select fields containing a User-ID.

**Related documentation:**

- [Person Accounts and Salesforce Data Events](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_person_accounts_salesforce_data_events.htm&type=5)
- [Configure Events for Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_configure_events_for_person_accounts.htm&type=5)
- [Configure Events for Business Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_configure_events_for_business_accounts.htm&type=5)
- [Configure Events for Person Account Related Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_configure_events_person_account_related_object.htm&type=5)

Comment: It worked, but i have 474 accounts based on the criteria i used because i did pull a filtered data extension earlier, however now when i used the same criteria for the entry source of the journey, it's been 30 min and i have just 4 accounts in there. Is there an explanation to this? @Markus Slabina

Comment: That is because a filtered data extension gives you all the records currently having those field values. A Salesforce data event however just listens to records created and/or updated that upon creation or update match your criteria. So this isn‘t suitable if you like to have all the already present records in your journey. In that case an Automation and a data extension entry source would be more suitable.